# Quickreport - pagenumber does not increase when page changed

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, quickreports

I am using the OnNeedData feature with an array feeding a number of qrLabels in a detail band configuration - (Delphi 2010 and QuickRep5) - On a multi-page report, I need to detect every next page (2, 3, 4 etc) and modify the first line in the detail band.

Everything works fine except that the internal page number variable (QuickReport.QRprinter.pagenumber) does not increment before the first line is printed (or shown).

As an exemple, if I print a **spam removed** of labels with the caption equal to the page number,
the first line of page 2 will show **Page 1** and the rest of the lines on that page will show correctly **Page 2** same thing happens for all other pages.

Can someone help me to find a way to properly identify the beginning of a new page, I have tried `OnEndPage, OnStartPage, BeforePrint, etc.` without success - the counter always increment after the first line of the detail band has been printed...

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure that the `Quickrep1` has a `PageheaderBand`
- Then examine the `QuickRep1.QRPrinter.PageNumber` in the `OnBeforePrint` event handler of that `PageHeaderBand`.